# How to delete number from column A when found in column B on form submit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two columns of data and I am trying to delete a value in column A when finding in column B.I would like to delete duplicate numbers amongst the cell if possible, but most importantly delete duplicate numbers in H once found in column I [This the table I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkFww.png)
I am having trouble referencing my sheet in the app script test solution that you suggested.

On "team assign" form submit I would like for values in column H to be checked for matches/duplicates in I and if found remove itself from column H. ie 16 is in column H row 2, "team assign" form submit has added 16 to column I. 16 is removed from column h –

```
function deleteInColumn() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Project 
   Assigner").activate();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
var rga=sh.getRange(1,8,sh.getLastRow(),1);
var vA=rga.getValues();
var rgb=sh.getRange(1,9,sh.getLastRow(),1);
var vB=rgb.getValues();
var vB=vB.map(function(r){return r[0]});
 var s=0;
 for(var i=0;i-s<vA.length;i++) {
  if(vB.indexOf(vA[i-s][0])>-1) {
    vA.splice(i-s,1);
  s++;
}
 }
 rga.clearContent();
 sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,1).setValues(vA);
}`
```

Column A
1 2 4
4 3 6 5
2 9 7

Column B

2
4
1

Column A

365
97

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: On "team assign" form submit I would like for values in column H  to be checked for matches/duplicates in I and if found remove itself from column H. ie 16 is in column H row 2, "team assign" form submit has added 16 to column I. 16 is removed from column h

Comment: Put that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteAIfInB() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rga=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rga.getValues();
  var rgb=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vB=rgb.getValues();
  var vB=vB.map(function(r){return r[0]});
  var s=0;
  for(var i=0;i-s<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vB.indexOf(vA[i-s][0])>-1) {
      vA.splice(i-s,1);
      s++;
    }
  }
  rga.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,1).setValues(vA);
}
```